# Как быстро перенести проект с Laravel на Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, laravel, фреймворк

Был разработан небольшой корпоративный портал на Laravel 5.4, но теперь требуется развернуть аналог на фреймворке Yii2, потому что он принят в команде, которая будет развивать проект дальше. Есть знания в ООП PHP и MVC, но с Yii2 никогда не работал, как, с помощью каких материалов в ускоренном режиме разобраться и проделать этот перенос?

Comment: ухухух...интересно, это вообще возможно ли сделать))

Comment: Огорчу - никак) Ручками переписывайте

Comment: `принят в команде, которая будет развивать проект дальше` так пусть эта "команда" и переделывает, вы то тут при чем?

Comment: Я тоже буду в ней

Comment: @Северянин, а вы хотите некий парсер, который перекинет все данные и перепишет код под Yii?)) Как минимум, составьте ТЗ для программистов, чтобы им легче переписывать было.

Comment: Нет, не парсер, понятное дело, но может хоть какое-то существующее руководство, примеры

Comment: Код в принципе достаточно понятен и одинаков и там и там, я сам на данный момент занимаюсь тем же самым, проблем с "портированием" не возникало. А уж у команды, на мой взгляд точно не должно возникнуть